# Временное отключение Bluetooth соединения с отдельным устройством в Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

Есть ли возможность временно отключать устройство, чтобы в дальнейшем не проходить процедуру сопряжения?
Например, к смартфону подключен фитнес-браслет и гарнитура в автомобиле. Хочется иметь возможность оставить соединение с браслетом, но иногда отключать гарнитуру в авто.

Answer (score 0):

У андроида нет возможности получить список "подключенных в данный момент" устройств. Список всех "спаренных" устройств (независимо от того, подключено оно сейчас или нет) можно получить так:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
```

Вы можете использовать broadcast receiver для получения [ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED) с информацией о подключении устройства.

Начиная с 4.3 (API 18) появился метод [getConnectionState()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothManager.html#getConnectedDevices(int))